# We need a [dungeons-and-dragons-5e] synonym, please and thank you!

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I just realised that part of why we've been getting 5e questions tagged [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) instead of [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) is because someone typing in "dungeo…" isn't going to see the 5e tag pop up.

I would do it, but you can't propose a non-existent tag as a synonym. (And I don't want to abuse some poor question with an arbitrary edit just to make the tag exist long enough for synonym voting…)

Could a mod create [dungeons-and-dragons-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons-5e) as a synonym of [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)?

We'll still get people mistagging with [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) when they mean [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), but this should cut it down somewhat.

Comment: I added the synonym.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**

This is a really great point, and something we overlooked with the transition from dnd-next to dnd-5e.

[image: Concur]